# Convert unix timestamp column to day of week in R

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am working with a data frame in **R** labeled "mydata". The first column, labled "ts" contains unix timestamp fields. I'd like to convert these fields to days of the week.

I've tried using strptime and POSIXct functions but I'm not sure how to execute them properly:

```
> strptime(ts, "%w")
```

--Returned this error:

> "Error in as.character(x) :    cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'"

I also just tried just converting it to human-readable format with POSIXct:

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct(ts, origin="1970-01-01"))
```

--Returned this error:

> "Error in as.POSIXct.default(ts, origin = "1970-01-01") : 
>         do not know how to convert 'ts' to class “POSIXct”"

Update: Here is what ended up working for me:

```
> mydata$ts <- as.Date(mydata$ts)
```

then

```
> mydata$ts <- strftime( mydata$ts , "%w" )
```

Comment: Include sample data using `dput`.

Comment: `ts` is the function that creates time series objects. Perhaps you meant to write `strptime(mydata$ts, "%w")`

Comment: Tried that and it output 10k rows that look like this: _[9997] "2013-06-09" "2013-06-09" "2013-06-09"_   but it doesn't appear like the actual contents of the data frame changed.

Comment: @pas I think you will want to use `strftime`

Comment: @pas you have to assign the output to an object, in this case `mydata$ts <- strftime( mydata$ts , ... )`

Comment: After trying your suggestion @SimonO101, I get this **"Error: '...' used in an incorrect context"** --Running that last command James suggested froze my computer because it's such a large dataset (27mb)

Comment: @pas the `...` was a placeholder for the other arguments you need to type in yourself! Try `mydata$ts <- strftime( mydata$ts , "%w" )` and may I suggest you familiarise yourself with some of the tutorials under the [**info**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) page of the `r` tag.

Comment: @SimonO101 sorry! I misunderstood-thought it had some connection to the ‘...’ argument. Could I assign the output back into the ts column? I'm really not familiar with R -- trying to look into how to assign output to objects now...

Comment: Thanks @SimonO101 -- I'll check it out. Also when I try that, I get *Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x, tz = tz) : 'origin' must be supplied* -- I'll keep looking and thanks for the help

Comment: @pas that's *exactly* what the `mydata$ts <-` does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need to go all the way to `strftime` when `POSIXlt` gives you this directly, and `strftime` calls `as.POSIXlt`.

```
wday <- function(x) as.POSIXlt(x)$wday

wday(Sys.time()) # Today is Sunday
## [1] 0
```

There is also the `weekdays` function, if you want character rather than numeric output:

```
weekdays(Sys.time())
## [1] "Sunday"
```