# Convert numeric (integer64 class) UNIX timestamp to date time class

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, unix-timestamp, integer64

Similar Q&A everywhere, but none helped me to overcome the following error
(I am trying to convert unix time to date-time format):

```
> cur196$time
integer64
  [1] 1566204590000 1566204585000 1566204580000 1566204570000 1566204560000 1566204550000 1566204531000 1566204525000 1566204521000 1566204501000
 [11] 1566204495000 1566204491000 1566204481000 1566204464000 1566204461000 1566204451000 1566204441000 1566204434000 1566204431000 1566204420000
 [21] ...
>   cur196$time <- as.POSIXct(cur196$time, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")
Error in as.POSIXct.default(cur196$time, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT") : 
  do not know how to convert 'cur196$time' to class “POSIXct”
```

EDIT:

```
> dput(head(cur196$time))
structure(c(7.73807882277875e-312, 7.73807879807547e-312, 7.73807877337218e-312, 
7.73807872396562e-312, 7.73807867455905e-312, 7.73807862515249e-312
), class = "integer64")
```

EDIT 2:

@zx8754 thank you very much for changing the title and thus pointing out the real problem - unix time stamps are in miliseconds and thus to large for conversion.

Comment: can you add `dput(head(cur196$time))` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Convert UNIX epoch to Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456241/convert-unix-epoch-to-date-object)

Comment: OK, it could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007023/convert-unix-timestamp-column-to-day-of-week-in-r . But, I do not know how to adapt the proposed solution to my example.

Comment: Glad to help. Please remove the "SOLUTION" from your question and post it as answer below: `"Your Answer"`.

Comment: By the way, your solution didn't work for dput example data provided in the question.

Comment: By mistake, I used to mix up original data and those already divided by 1000. I changed this to keep the question usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your data has the class `integer64` from the `bit64` package. You need to convert it to a normal integer with `as.integer()`, while the `bit64` package is loaded. Then you can use `as.POSIXct()` on it.

But probably you should look into how you imported the data and why it is saved that way in the first place. Does it need to be a 64-bit integer?

Comment: Correct! After I realised that my data are in miliseconds I also find out that they must be divided by 1000 (seems that this automatically creates normal integers). Like this: cur196$time <- as.POSIXct(cur196$time/1000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")